# Python: Convert dictionary of timestamped values to timestamped list for signal processing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have temperature data that is timestamped (incrementing randomly) in milliseconds in a dictionary like this:

```
{0: 30, 5: 20, 10: 50, 15: 30, 20: 50}
```

where `0,5,10.... (dict.keys())` represent the time in ms and `30,20,50... (dict.values())` represent the temperature values in Celsius, typically about 1-2 seconds of data (1k-10k samples).

I want to convert (upsample) this dict to a list so I can apply convolution on it, desired output:

```
list=[(combo of 2 closest points weighted by 1-distance to point) for x in range(min_time,max_time,specified_interval)]
```

where each point is `(value_on_left*(distance_between_left_and_right_values-distance_to_point_from_left) + value_on_right*(distance_between_left_and_right_values-distance_to_point_from_right))/distance_between_left_and_right_values`

eg in this case for an interval of 2 ms: `list=[30, 26, 22, 26, 38, 50, 42, 34, 34, 42, 50]`

The values are not always spaced by 5 ms, they appear at random (which is why they're in a dict format in the first place)

How do I do this/ do this efficiently?

Comment: Wouldn't linear interpolation be more meaningful, i.e, 2ms is closer to 0ms than 4ms, so `temp[2ms] > temp[4ms]`?

Comment: Linear interpolation was the answer, thanks @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

**Data**

```
interval = 2 # set interval
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: 30, 5: 20, 10: 50, 15: 30, 20: 50}, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = ['ms', 'temp']
df.index = df['ms']

i_df = pd.DataFrame(range(df['ms'].max())[::interval], columns = ['interval']) # create interval dataframe

i_df['time_left'] = i_df['interval'].map(lambda x: df[df['ms'] <= x]['ms'].max())
i_df['time_right'] = i_df['interval'].map(lambda x: df[df['ms'] > x]['ms'].min())
i_df['value_left'] = i_df['time_left'].map(lambda x: df.loc[x, 'temp'])i_df['value_right'] = i_df['time_right'].map(lambda x: df.loc[x, 'temp'])
```

```
print(i_df.to_string())

   interval  time_left  time_right  value_left  value_right
0         0          0           5          30           20
1         2          0           5          30           20
2         4          0           5          30           20
3         6          5          10          20           50
4         8          5          10          20           50
5        10         10          15          50           30
6        12         10          15          50           30
7        14         10          15          50           30
8        16         15          20          30           50
9        18         15          20          30           50
```

**Solution**

```
i_df['signal_score'] = ((i_df['value_left']*((i_df['time_right'] - i_df['time_left'])-(i_df['time_right'] - i_df['interval'])) 
                               + i_df['value_right']*((i_df['time_right'] - i_df['time_left'])-(i_df['interval'] - i_df['time_left'])))
                                /((i_df['time_right'] - i_df['time_left'])))
```

**Output**

```
print(i_df.to_string())

   interval  time_left  time_right  value_left  value_right  signal_score
0         0          0           5          30           20          20.0
1         2          0           5          30           20          24.0
2         4          0           5          30           20          28.0
3         6          5          10          20           50          44.0
4         8          5          10          20           50          32.0
5        10         10          15          50           30          30.0
6        12         10          15          50           30          38.0
7        14         10          15          50           30          46.0
8        16         15          20          30           50          46.0
9        18         15          20          30           50          38.0
```

Comment: Uses a lot of space, any chance we can make this a function without a pd dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean takes a lot of space? The code is too long for you? Or this isn't efficient enough memory wise?

Comment: Just edited to remove use of apply (makes it more efficient) and shortened the variables names

Comment: memory wise, we're creating 4 variables per index

Comment: There are 4 additional variables per index. You have to make the `interval ` and `signal_score` variables no matter what you do. If you find a better way id love to see!

Comment: I added another answer below that doesn't create the 4 additional variables. Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as above but doesn't create 4 additional variables. This is more efficient memory-wise. Hope this helps!

**Data**

```
interval = 2 # set interval
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: 30, 5: 20, 10: 50, 15: 30, 20: 50}, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = ['ms', 'temp']
df.index = df['ms']

i_df = pd.DataFrame(range(df['ms'].max())[::interval], columns = ['interval']) # create interval dataframe
```

```
print(i_df.head().to_string())

   interval
0         0
1         2
2         4
3         6
4         8
```

**Solution**

```
def getSignalScore(interval, df):
    time_left = df[df['ms'] <= interval]['ms'].max()
    time_right = df[df['ms'] > interval]['ms'].min()
    value_left = df.loc[time_left, 'temp']
    value_right = df.loc[time_right, 'temp']
    signal_score = ((value_left*((time_right - time_left)-(time_right - interval)) 
                               + value_right*((time_right - time_left)-(interval - time_left)))
                                /((time_right - time_left)))
    return signal_score


i_df['signal_score'] = i_df['interval'].map(lambda x: getSignalScore(x, df))
```

**Output**

```
print(i_df.to_string())

   interval  signal_score
0         0          20.0
1         2          24.0
2         4          28.0
3         6          44.0
4         8          32.0
5        10          30.0
6        12          38.0
7        14          46.0
8        16          46.0
9        18          38.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Linear Interpolation was a good solution.
[https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html][1]